# Using DISTINCT, COUNT AND SUBSTRING in a statement

Tags: mysql, count, substring

I have a `id` column below

[image: id column]

I want to `count` the 3 unique char in the column starting from 3 on the right. So I did this: `SELECT SUBSTRING(id,3,3) FROM lhr` and I get this result:

[image]

Now how do I count the total in the `id` column such as `A00` = 7 and `A90` = 1? I try `Count As` such as this : `SELECT SUBSTRING(id,3,3), COUNT(*) AS 'total' FROM lhr`

but it did not worked. I don't get the result i wanted. The result I get is `total` = 8. Help me please and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select mydata, count(*) from 
(SELECT SUBSTRING(id,3,3) as mydata FROM lhr) a
group by mydata
```

That should do it for you.

Better method:

```
select substring(id,3,3), count(*) 
from 1hr 
group by substring(id,3,3)
```

Comment: Hello, your second method does worked for me. Thank you.